# I'm having problems simplifying this discrete-time fourier tranform

Tags: fourier-transform, math, dtft

I have this problem, and I can't get to the solution.
$$X(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} {(0.6)^{|n|}[u(n + 10) − u(n − 11)]}e^{-j\omega n}$$

The solution is
$$X(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{0.64 − 2(0.6)^{11} \cos(11ω) + 2(0.6)^{12} \cos(10ω)}{1.36 − 1.2 \cos(ω)}
$$

But I don't know how to get there, i think it is related to a series(geometric, maybe) and things like Euler formula but still not able to find a way to get there. This is an exercise(3.3.2) from Proakis and Inge book, *Digital Signal Processing using Matlab*.

Comment: Homework?  I can see three separate properties of the Fourier Transform that you can use to simplify this if you apply them in turn -- can you name one?

Comment: Linearity, I think.

Comment: The very outermost operation going on there is summing $x_2(n) = {(0.6)^{|n|}[u(n + 10) − u(n − 11)]}e^{-j\omega n}$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.  If you knew the Fourier transform of $x_2$, what would be your overall Fourier transform?  (Yes, the Socratic Method is named after a guy who was forced by his colleagues to drink poison.  None the less, I'm hoping you'll have an "aha" moment here).

Answer (score 0):

$$X(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-10}^{\infty} {(0.6)^{|n|}}e^{-j\omega n} -   \sum_{n=11}^{\infty} {(0.6)^{|n|}}e^{-j\omega n}$$

Comment: This is kinda hard to read ... Use Latex maybe?

Comment: Please do not answer obvious homework problems directly.  We have a policy here of _helping_ people answer homework problems, by finding where they're stuck and giving that missing bit the prof missed, or helping them separate the problem into tractable bits -- but we do not **do homework** here.  Just an answer with no effort behind it isn't what homework is about: it doesn't serve the original poster, or the engineering community at large.

Comment: This is not homework, I'm just solving the exercises of the book. And I have simplified the summation limiting it by the unit step subtraction bounds, and also expressed the modulos of n by separating and tracking when n gets positive, but from that into the final solution is a blurr.

Comment: If you can link me to an example that can help for me to solve this one, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Derteckpt: please *edit your question* with the comment that it's not homework and that you're self-studying.